# Convert Spesific CONCAT MYSQL to PDO Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have trouble to convert mysql to PDO query laravel

```
SELECT * FROM tablebarang WHERE 'baju koko yi 067 merah' LIKE CONCAT('%',sku,'%') LIMIT 1
```

can u help me to convert it to PDO query laravel ? i will appreciate if you can help me

I Need result like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Olub.png

**Software Version :**
10.1.35-MariaDB-cll-lve
Laravel Framework 5.5.42

**UPDATE :**
This is my new script update suggest from Mr. @Tschitsch

```
$result = DB::table("tablebarang")
              ->whereRaw("? LIKE CONCAT('%',sku,'%')", $nameProduct)
              ->limit(1)
              ->first();
dd($result->sku);
```

The result this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlOFs.png

This result error because dd($result) return null.
I make sure the table and query is correct, any else suggestion please.

Comment: `DB::selectRaw(...);` or `DB::select(DB::raw(...));` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: hi, thank you, i have try but same just return blank

Comment: DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM tablebarang WHERE '".$nameProduct."' LIKE CONCAT('%',sku,'%') LIMIT 1"))

Comment: Are you using `->get()` or `->first()`? The query isn't actually executed in your code currently :P Something like `$result = DB::select(...)->get();`

Comment: Call to a member function get() on array

Comment: this is my script : $result = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM tablebarang WHERE '$nameProduct' LIKE CONCAT('%',sku,'%') LIMIT 1"))->get();

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm wrong; `DB::select()` executes immediately; last time I used `select` was with `DB::table(...)->select(...)->get()`; seems to have some different logic.

Comment: Probably don't need the concat; you could just do `LIKE '%sku%'`. Is `sku` supposed to be a variable?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'WHERE 'Tas Koper Pink Polo [ANTI PECAH] Ukuran 24 Inch' LIKE CONCAT('%',sku,'%') LIMIT 1' in 'field list' (SQL: select `WHERE 'Tas Koper Pink Polo [ANTI PECAH] Ukuran 24 Inch' LIKE CONCAT('%',sku,'%') LIMIT 1` from `tablebarang`)

Comment: Ok, start editing your question please; don't post code in comments; its impossible to read

Comment: 'sku' is column sql and the variable is $nameProduct

Comment: oke, please see my update

Comment: Hmm... Honestly, I'm afraid I don't understand your query... I don't think I'll be able to help much beyond this point sorry.

Comment: it's ok mr @TimLewis, i very greatfull for u, for last maybe you can see my images https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Olub.png, probably you understabd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$res = DB::table("tablebarang")
         ->whereRaw("? LIKE CONCAT('%',sku,'%')", $nameProduct)
         ->limit(1)
         ->get();
```

This is my database entry:

```
/*
mysql> select name from users;
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| 42 foo |
| bar 42 |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
*/
```

And here is the code I tested with

```
$nameProduct = "lorem IPSUM 42 FOO dolor sit amet";

$res = DB::table("users")
    ->whereRaw("? LIKE CONCAT('%',name,'%')", $nameProduct)
    ->limit(1)
    ->first();

dd($res->name); // output is "42 foo"
```

Comment: Hi @Tschitsch, thanks for answer before but the query return null, do you have alternative ?

Comment: @CyberSoftMedia Are you sure that you have a proper record in your database? I reproduced a same'ish query using a fresh laravel57 installation with a fresh mysql57 database.

Comment: Iam using Laravel Framework 5.5.42 and i doing like you said, please see in my question i have been update the script but still return null

Comment: @CyberSoftMedia Can you also visualize (a stripped down) db-record which you would like to match and also the value of `$nameProduct` that you are using.

Comment: Hi iam sorry, the code is working fine, the problem is in $nameProduct wrong looping so that variable always null.I really appreciate and very many thank for you Mr @Tschitsch